# How can I make an options menu for my game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make an options menu for my game where there are 2 settings. One setting disables all music that are in the game, and the other disables all sound effects. If the user chooses to disable all sound effects and not music, then when he exits the game and comes back to it, it should remember his settings. I have tried numerous times to create this sort of system, but it is not working for me at all. I don't know how to create it. Can anyone please help? I am fairly new at action script.

All sounds are accessed from library

Comment: What do you have so far? Where is this game going to be? Online? Where are you going to store the settings (_it should remember_)

Comment: Well so far I have 2 mute buttons, one to disable the sound and the other to disable the music. I tried numerous attempts with the code, but none worked. This game is going to go online, I want to store the settings in a local folder like a shared object. I tried making 2 text fields..if clicked they would go to 0, and disable sound and music. If clicked again, they would go to 100. But I don't know how to disable specific music and sounds from the library

Comment: @User2896120 has anyone provided a suitable answer? If so, you should mark it as correct. If not, try updating your question to include more information on what you require additional clarification on...

Answer (score 0):

Use SoundChannel to create and control separate sounds.
use a SharedObject to store user choice.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Comment: Are you Senekis from Kongregate? If yes, it's good to see you here as well.

Comment: Yep. Hi, Vesperbot. (:

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a sound manager class of static functionality, which will have two public Boolean properties which then you can set separately using your options menu. Then, the class will check these booleans each time you want a sound to be played (for this, use its function to play sounds). An example:

```
public class SoundManager {
    private var _musicOn:Boolean;
    private var _soundOn:Boolean;
    private var _currentMusicChannel:SoundChannel;
    private var _currentMusicSelected:Sound; // what to start when music is enabled
    public static function get musicOn():Boolean { return _musicOn; }
    public static function set musicOn(value:Boolean):void {
        if (value==_musicOn) return;
        _musicOn=value;
        if (_musicOn) _currentMusicChannel=_currentMusicSelected.play();
        else if (_currentMusicChannel) {
            _currentMusicChannel.stop();
            _currentMusicChannel=null;
        }
    }
    public static function get soundOn():Boolean { return _soundOn; }
    public static function set soundOn(value:Boolean):void { _soundOn=value; } 
    // a simple version, as this is an example
    public static function playSound(someSound:String):void {
        var aSound:Sound=getSoundFromString(someSound); // TODO
        // ^ you have to devise a method to convert strings to sounds
        if (isMusic(aSound)) {
            // TODO, you should have either one music or a set of em, so if you're
            // trying to play a music, this should return true, otherwise false
            _currentMusicSelected=aSound;
            if (_musicOn) _currentMusicChannel=aSound.play();
        } else {
            // a simpler version, the more advanced version should allow instant mute
            if (_soundOn) aSound.play();
        }
    }
    // some other functions are missing from here, as well as sound library and support stuff
}
```