# How to turn off specific sounds using an array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a possible way where I can turn specific sounds off using an array? Some of these sounds are off, but I want them to be universally off throughout. So if the user goes to the scene where there is the sound that plays, it won't play.

Comment: I was going to try edit this into a "better" question for you but now even I'm MORE confused..!! Do you want a volume mute? Like sound on/off in a music player? Are your sounds already in the timeline or loaded as external files? Please re-edit your question if you still need help with it..

Answer (score 0):

Remove sounds from scenes altogether, as their playback is not controlled via code. Instead, use any of the approached provided to you earlier (say [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19920649/1627055)).